# Opencv/Python - how can I get the coordinates of detected areas after image processing

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, bots

My goal is to write a bot playing minesweeper, but I get stuck at the point, when I want to tell the bot, where the squares are. I tried a lot of different functions.
First of all, my tool grabs a screenshot of a predefined area. This picture looks like this:[screenshot of game board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv6u3.png)

after that I want to fill a numpy array in this way:

```
info_map = np.ones((board_height=9, board_width=9),
                   dtype = np.uint8)*11
>array([[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
        [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
        ...
        [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]], dtype=uint8
```

11 stands in this example for "undiscovered" or a blue, untouched square.

with the help of the opencv square detector from the examples I get a huge list with detected points (nearly 5000points for a 9x9 grid). I don't know how to remove all the noise, to get the right coords of the corners. so I came to the next example showing below:

**My last try was the following:**

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys   

def canny_edge():
"""This function is taken from SentDex from one of his fantastic Python
tutorials.
https://pythonprogramming.net/canny-edge-detection-gradients-python-opencv-tutorial/
"""
for fn in glob('full_snap.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    while(1):
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
        upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
        #res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)
        laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img, cv2.CV_64F)
        #edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)

        cv2.imwrite(os.getcwd() + '\\laplace.png', laplacian)
```

**This is the saved image:**
[laplace.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmoPu.png)

here I tried to do a for loop over the Laplacian to check if the pixel is blue or not, and take the first one as an anchor to tell the bot, that from the anchor (starting point) there is a square every x pixel in the x direction and in the y. But is there a better way to do it automatically?

but my main question is how to connect the image processed squares into an numpy array, that I can tell the bot click_square(1,2) and he knows at which pixels is the square from row 1 and column 2.

**Hint:** My coordinate system starts in the upper left corner of the screen.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Doesnt this sample in opencv do exactly that? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py

Comment: this is the approach i used first, and after your answer while i saved the images my functions did with this example i get the answer i think. a few days ago the squares.py gave my the huge list with the 5000 points, and every corner was build with maybe 10 different points. But a few seconds ago i get the right answer i think. now i need only the center point of the thick points, drawing from squares.py line 51. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what minesweeper is but from what i understood, you want to know which tiles are blue and then make necessary changes to your numpy array (correct me if its something else, i'll edit or remove the answer).

Here's the output after making four tiles blue:

[image]

What i did ?

First i thresholded the blue colour, found contours in the range approximately as that of your tiles.

Found their centers to see what pattern they follow -

[image]

They were all separated by some 55-57 pixels (both x,y coordinates). Rest is simple.

```
for i in range(len(coords)):
np_arr[int(coords[i][1]/57)][int(coords[i][0]/57)]=0
```

The blue tile coordinates are stored in coords, np_arr is my array.

Comment: yeah, you did it and i think i get the idea behind your doing.

i have only 2 questions:
- are the values in your "coords" only the center coords of the tiles or the coords of all the corners?
- wich range for the color blue did you take? the "normal" upper_blue/lower_blue (HSV color space) from the typical opencv examples or special values of my blue tiles?

Comment: Only the centers for now. That'll suffice. You can add a range for centers but that is redundant i think. I thresholded the image in HSV because direct gray thresholding might ruin it for you if if there are other similar gray level things later in the image. lower_red = np.array([100,80,50]). You can play around a little Don't get misleaded by the blue in that image. It's just a blank array with (255,0,0) drawn for some blue tiles in the hsv range

Comment: Thank you, i did it. The next few days i would answer this question with the code i used to solve my problem in the end. To find the right pixel values and give it to opencv was really hard because of rgb/bgr and hsv :-) but now i made it.

Comment: That's nice ! Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Make an opencv trackbar for pixel hsv, bgr values to easy the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used. I have to rearange my Dataframe in the end, but only for better human reading. I think there are a lot of possible improvement in my code, but i´m happy that the behaviour of my code is good enough for my needs.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = cv2.imread('full_snap.png')
"""
some of my blue pixels
R: between 98 and 128
G: between 176 and 211
B: between 255

h: between 210 and 200
s: between 100 and 48
v: between 68 and 100

hsv/2 in opencv and opencv uses BGR not RGB
"""

blue_MIN = np.array([255, 176, 98])
blue_MAX = np.array([255, 211, 128])
"""
https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/
"""

# find the blue pixels and save it in frame_threshed
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(img, blue_MIN, blue_MAX)

# find contours in the thresholded image
cnts = cv2.findContours(frame_threshed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

#print("cnts", cnts)
i = len(cnts)
print("i", i)

# we know we're gonna have x rows of data, where x is the product of
# board_width * board_height
numberOfRows = 81

# check if the length of cnts are euqal to the number of rows/ number of tiles
# then go further

# TODO

# create x,y data
# df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(numberOfRows, 0), columns=('x', 'y'))
d = []
print("d", d)
print(type(d))


for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    # fill the data with the coords
    d.append({'tilenumber': i, 'X-Value': cX, 'Y-Value': cY})

    # decrease i to go backwards, because tile number 81 is the first contour
    i-=1
    # draw the center of the shape on the image
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# only for debugging
print("x,y dataframe", df)
cv2.imshow("Image_with_contours",img)

# Destroys all of the HighGUI windows.
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you all for the help!
Robinarthur